# {"error":"unsupported_grant_type"} for angular call

Tags: angularjs, typescript, asp.net-web-api, jwt

My api post call for retrieving a jwt token responds with 400 error. Here is my api angular call.  I tried with URLSearchparams too.

```
authenticateUser(userid: string, password: string) {
        // var authorization_grant = "password";
        // let body = new URLSearchParams();
        // body.append('username', userid);
        // body.append('password', password);
        // body.append('grant_type', authorization_grant);
        let body = 'userName=' + userid+ '&password=' +password +'&grant_type=password';
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this.http.post(this.config.apiBaseUrl + '/token', body, options).retry(3).map((res: Response) => {
            if (res.status == 200) {
                this.validatedUser = res.json();
                localStorage.setItem("access_token", this.validatedUser.access_token);
            }
            return this.validatedUser;
        })
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to get a token when you try with Fiddler or Postman?

Comment: @jps Yes, with postman I get token

Comment: @user3154990 after checking the error message I think there is some issue with the grant_type params.  You need to pass a valid parameter  . Can you please check that again. Because all seems good .

Comment: @baswajit-rout my api grant_type is password. It is working with postman though, I get token there. I just tried it different too like let body = "username=" + userid+ "&password=" +password +"&grant_type='password'" which also failed

Comment: You may need to urlencode the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, after investigating the traffic in Fiddler tool, I compared the headers when called from postman vs angular.

**On Client-Side:**
I removed line headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); from my code which resolved this issue.

**On Server-Side**
Most importantly I moved app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll) line of code on top of app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer where I generate token in my startup.cs.

Thanks @jps, @biswajit-rout and @Ruard Van Elburg for looking into it.